# Finding node using HTML agility pack

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

Here is the google chrome dev tool to get the elment im looking for.

[image]

Here are all the different ways I have tried to get the nodes..

HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();

```
            doc.LoadHtml(webObject.Html);

            // HtmlNode footer = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants().SingleOrDefault(y => y. == "boardPickerInner");
            // "//div[@class='boardPickerInner']"
            //var y = (from HtmlNode node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//")
            //         where node.InnerText == "boardPickerInner"
            //         select node.InnerHtml);

              HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode bodyNode = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//nameAndIcons");

              var xq = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//td[@class='nameAndIcons']");

            var x = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("");

            HtmlNode nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//[@class='nameAndIcons']");

            var boards = nodes.SelectNodes("//*[@class='nameAndIcons']");
```

Can someone explain what I am doing wrong..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have multiple `span` elements with `class="nameAndIcons"`. So in order to get them all you could use the `SelectNodes` function:

```
var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//span[@class='nameAndIcons'"])
```

Comment: what is document element? documentnodes?

Comment: It's pointing to the actual DOM tree and is used to perform queries on it.

Comment: I dont have a DocumentElement within the htmlagility class. Is this an extension..?

Comment: Try `DocumentNode` instead. I guess they might have renamed it in newer versions.

Comment: i did, it worked but the elements im looking for dont exist. is there a way to load the DOM. thank you btw